# Unifying python dicts?

Tags: python

Does anone have a fair algorithm for unifying (almost) arbitrary dicts? That is, given the dicts

```
a = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: [1,2,3]}
b = {4: 4, 3: [5], 5: {'a': 0, 'b': {}}
c = {3: [{'A': '0'}], 5: {'b': {'B': 1}}}

unify (a, b, c)
```

yields

```
{1: 1, 
 2: 2, 
 3: [1, 2, 3, 5, {'A': '0'}], 
 4: 4,     
 5: {'a': 0, 'b': {'B': 1}}
}
```

I keep wanting a generic solution. I wind up searching for a generic solution a couple of times a year and not finding one (*no Google, unify from unification and unify from union is not the same word!*), and I keep putting off writing one myself. I very well know that programming Prolog leads to an odd pespective on life, but hey, how can one have a recursive dict/key/value-store and not have unification?

I have in the past needed ordering, hence lists, and back then I wound up not going for a generic version but hardcoding. This time around I don't actually need unification of sets/lists at all, and the fall back is to once again hardcode as I know what the keys can be ahead of time. But: If there already were a generic solution out there, I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel again and again. It's just wrong to have to do that.

The really pythonic solution would probably start with a `__unify__`-method on all things that can be unified, it's that basic.

Comment: Well my friend, what did you try so far? Writing a loop that would do such task seems pretty straightforward, and I doubt that there is a made function, so get codding!

Comment: look at the docs http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/

Comment: what is expected result for key which values in different dicts has different types?

Comment: and this link (section 2.5) http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/featstruct.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck as to how to iterate through a dictionary, using a for loop iterates through the keys:

```
>>> for i in {1: "abc"}: print i
1
```

As the comments say, please specify what problems you're facing rather than asking SO to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Like zodiac mentioned, it's difficult to answer with out a direct problem; however, I'll try for a solution.

```
#Merge Lists of Dictionaries Functions
def merge_lists(l1, l2, key):
    merged = {}
    for item in l1+l2:
        if item[key] not in merged:
            merged[item[key]] = item
    return [val for (_, val) in merged.items()]
```

tell me how this works